# gsub and hitting on a regex which I don't want to in rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is really simple question but rarely use regex's so I apologize. I am writing a simple view helper for some simple UBBcodes

I want t o be able to call:

```
<%=arc_format "[quote]hello  you from me[\quote]" %>
```

and have it return:

```
<div class='start-quote'>
  hello you from me
</div>
```

my helper:

```
def arc_format str
 str=str.gsub(/\[quote\]/,'<div class="start-quote">') # works but adds in second quote; seems to hit off second isntance
 str=str.gsub!(/\[\\quote\]/,'</div>')
 str.html_safe
end
```

the output is

```
<div class='start-quote'>
 hello you from me
<div class='start-quote'>
</div>
```

How do I get that second regex from not replacing?

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash is not being carried over. Try:

```
> string = "[quote]hello  you from me[\quote]"

> puts string
[quote]hello  you from me[quote]
```

Should be:

```
> string = "[quote]hello  you from me[\\quote]"

> puts string
[quote]hello  you from me[\quote]
```

Is it supposed to be `[\quote]`? I would have thought `[/quote]` makes more sense.

Comment: sorry, been one of those mornings, you're right regarding ending slash

Comment: Simple mistakes. We all make 'em.